# Usage of the word 'tenfold'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Sentence:

I want to read **tenfold** faster than now = I want to read **ten times** faster than now

Question:

Can I use the word ['tenfold'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tenfold) in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you can, but if you check [*tenfold*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tenfold) examples you will see most examples involve increase/decrease or rise/fall (change words rather than static state ones).

For your example, I would stay with "ten times" Using *tenfold* this might be better:

> I want to realize a **tenfold increase** in my reading speed.

Comment: I want a tenfold increase in my reading speed. Not realize.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure I understand the objection.  The second definition pulled up by Google for "realize" is "cause (something desired or anticipated) to happen."  user3169's use of the word here seems completely natural to me.